# Require help validating data inside MySQL

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements, exists

I currently have 2 different sections for this program, the first half takes the users input from a web page and then transfers it over onto a PHP side which will access MySQL and display the requested information.

Example: If I enter AX12 for the ID it will display information for that ID which does infact exist, but if I enter AX13 (which doesn't) it will display blank information, so I'm wondering if someone can show me how I can validate this once the information has been transferred over onto the PHP side. So if it detects that the information you've submitted does not exist simply display a message saying "ID DOES NOT EXIST" or something along those lines.

Here's the code for the PHP side if you need it for more information.

```
<?php

$part_number = $_GET['txtInput'];
$part_description;
$units_on_hand;
$item_class;
$warehouse_number;
$unit_price;

$query;
$result_set;
$connection;
$record;

echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<title>SQL Application</title>";
echo "<style type = 'text/css'>body{text-align: center; background-color: #CC3333; color: #660000; font-size: 30;}</style>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";

echo "<center><h1>SQL Application</h1></center>";

echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";

$connection = @mysql_connect("localhost","m_stanicic","")
        or die ("\n\n PROBLEM CONNECTING TO DATABASE! \n" . mysql_error() . "\n\n");

mysql_select_db("m_stanicicdb");

$query = "select * from part where part_number = '" . $part_number . "'";

$result_set = mysql_query($query)
        or die ("\n\n PROBLEM WITH QUERY! . \n" . mysql_error() . "\n\n");

$record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set);

if($part_number == "")
{
        //
}
else
{
        $part_description = $record['part_description'];
        $units_on_hand = $record['units_on_hand'];
        $item_class = $record['item_class'];
        $warehouse_number = $record['warehouse_number'];
        $unit_price = $record['unit_price'];

        echo "<center>";
        echo "<table border='1' width=400 style ='table-layout:fixed' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>";
        echo "<col width = 200>";
        echo "<col width = 200>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th colspan='2'>DETAILS OF THE PART YOU REQUESTED</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>part_description</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $part_description . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>units_on_hand</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $units_on_hand . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>item_class</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $item_class . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>warehouse_number</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $warehouse_number . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>unit_price</td>";
        echo "<td>$" . $unit_price . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</center>";

        mysql_close($connection);
}

echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";

echo "<input type = 'button' value = 'RETURN' style = 'width: 75px; height: 75px;' onclick = \"javascript:window.location.href = 'jdpset1_4.html'\">";

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 1):

You aren't validating anywhere that the result did return any data at all. Right after your call to `mysql_query()`, you should use `mysql_num_rows()` to see how many rows were returned by your query -- if `mysql_num_rows($result_set)` is zero, your query returned no data.

Notice how `$part_number` is never modified by `mysql_query()`, `mysql_fetch_array()` or any of those functions; so it will never be empty unless it started as such (rendering your current `if` almost useless).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the output of your query `$record`...

```
 if (count($record)==0) {
    echo "the ID you entered does not exist! Try again...";
 } else {   
    // code to output the part's details...
 }
```

put the `if (count...` part instead of ...

```
 if($part_number == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

from your code i notice 2 things

```
$query = "select * from part where part_number = '" . $part_number . "'";
```

as your part number is a string, i recommend you to use `LIKE` not `=`

```
$query = "select * from part where part_number LIKE '" . $part_number . "'";
```

another is inspect your record is returning in multidimensional array like

```
 $record = Array([0]=>array('part_description'=>A123...)).
```

then you must assign like so

```
$part_description = $record[0]['part_description'];
```

i hope it helps you